# optimize.curve_fit for an error function?

Tags: python, optimization, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm using optimize.curve_fit to fit a function that includes an error function.
On the first try I used math.erfc and got

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

On the second try I used scipy.special.erf and got [1. 1.] as the fit results, which I don't believe correctly reflects the given data.

Why is this happening / what alternative error function can I use to avoid these problems?
(Trying to figure out the parameters for a CDF of a Gaussian distribution.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Usually I'd give a small intro on how to ask a question, to provide some code to reproduce the problem, i.e. a minimum example that reproduces your problem, and some minimal set of data. In this case however, it is more or less clear. The first try did not work as `curve_fit` is sending arrays to the function and `math.erf()` cannot handle those. The second result very likely means that in your non-linear fit the starting values ( for `curve_fit` it is `1` for every parameter) are so off that no convergence takes place and you are left with those starting values. Cheers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.